# how to solve vue short if in v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I need to do a shortif in a v-model, but eslint gives the folowing problem:

> [vue/valid-v-model] 'v-model' directives require the attribute value
>   which is valid as LHS.eslint-plugin-vue

so the code works. but its not the way it needs to work.
this is the code i have now

```
<v-text-field 
v-show="field.type == 'String'"
v-model="_isMultiple(content_data[tabindex]) && subitem != null ? content_data[tabindex][subitem][field.name] 
: content_data[tabindex][field.name]" 
:label="field.name" 
:counter="field.counter" 
max-width="100px"
/>
```

So this code needs a little explanation to it.
I try to build this as an dynamic module. If I get an array back from my json response it needs to v-model the subitem. If I get an object back from the response it just needs to v-model that object.

The data (`content_data[tabindex]`) + field do i get from a v-for loop and other loops in my vue html
so I think its not an option to do a computed prop because
I can't get in the right data.

_isMultiple function code:

```js
_isMultiple(content_data) {
  return Array.isArray(content_data)
}
```

any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not use v-model, but build it on your own with value binding and event listening.

v-model is only a shorthand: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html.

By implementing it on your own you can use a method to set the values and a computed property to get it.